# Spring Security browser back button issue in IE and Firefox but not in Chrome

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot, browser-cache, spring-session

I am using spring security 4.1.1 along with spring 4.3.4 and Thymeleaf 3.x after logout when I click on browser back button in chrome browser its still in login page but in IE and Firefox due to caching its redirecting to the page from where I clicked on logout. In redirected page if I click on any button or link its directing to login page meaning it is issue with cache and in Firefox I can see that as BFCache

Here is my securityConfiguration file

```
 @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {

        RequestMatcher matcher = new AntPathRequestMatcher("/login");
        DelegatingRequestMatcherHeaderWriter headerWriter =
            new DelegatingRequestMatcherHeaderWriter(matcher,new XFrameOptionsHeaderWriter());

        //to disable loading application back button after logout
        httpSecurity
            .headers()
                .defaultsDisabled()
                    .cacheControl().and()
                .contentTypeOptions().and().addHeaderWriter(headerWriter)
                .httpStrictTransportSecurity()
                    .includeSubDomains(true)
                    .maxAgeInSeconds(31536000).and()
                .frameOptions().sameOrigin().xssProtection().block(false);


        httpSecurity
            /*.csrf()
                .disable()*/
            .authorizeRequests()
                .expressionHandler(webExpressionHandler())
                .antMatchers("/forgotPwd", "/resetPwd*", "/successRegister*",
                        "/registrationConfirm*", "/registration.html", "/user/registration")
                .permitAll()
                // .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/api","/api/**").hasRole("ROLE_ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login.html")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/home.html")
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .failureUrl("/login.html?error=true")
                // .successHandler(myAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
                .failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler)
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .sessionManagement()
                .invalidSessionUrl("/invalidSession.html")
                .sessionFixation().none()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .deleteCookies("remember-me", "SESSION")
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login.html")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .rememberMe()
                .rememberMeServices(rememberMeServices())
                .tokenValiditySeconds(86400)
                .rememberMeCookieName("remember-me")
                .and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");
    }
```

How to make IE and Firefox disable the Cache?

How to disable this?

For full working application code check my [github](https://github.com/rajadileepkolli/springsecuredthymeleafapp)

Comment: I'm guessing you need to set `cacheControl` appropriately, though not sure how you are going to do that without a filter for a specific browser.